# how to solve a set of expression

Tags: python, expression, sympy, equation

how to solve a set of expressions in Python, not numerical calcualtion but purely analytic way?

I checked several functions of sympy which seems unable to do the work.

Assuming we are going to find the expression for x1,x2,x3 and x4 with following equations:

`x1 = a*s+b*x2 + c`

`x2 = (m+n) * x3 + d`

`x3 = l*s + k*x4 + e`

`x4 = i*s + j*x1 + f`

where x1,x2,x3,x4,a,b,c,d,e,f,i,j,k,l,m,n are all symbols.

How to reach the result for such problems in Python.

Comment: what you need to find?

Answer (score 0):

First get the "paper" equations into SymPy Equalities:

```
>>> from sympy.utilities.iterables import reshape
>>> eqs=reshape(S('''(
    x1 = a*s+b*x2 + c
    x2 = (m+n) * x3 + d
    x3 = l*s + k*x4 + e
    x4 = i*s + j*x1 + f)'''.strip().replace(
    '\n',',').replace('=',',')), (2,))
>>> eqs = [Eq(*i) for i in eqs]
```

Then solve the equations (see `solve` docstring):

```
>>> solve(eqs, var('x1:5'))
{x4: (a*s + b*d + b*(e + l*s)*(m + n) + c - (-f - i*s)/j)/(-b*k*(m + n) + 1/j),
 x3: e + k*(a*s + b*d + b*(e + l*s)*(m + n) + c - (-f - i*s)/j)/(-b*k*(m+ n) + 1/j) + 
     l*s, 
 x1: (-f - i*s)/j + (a*s + b*d + b*(e + l*s)*(m + n) + c - (-f - i*s)/j)/(j*(-b*k*(m 
     + n) + 1/j)),
 x2: d + (m + n)*(e + k*(a*s + b*d + b*(e + l*s)*(m + n) + c - (-f - 
     i*s)/j)/(-b*k*(m + n) + 1/j) + l*s)}
```

As noted [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/14694#issuecomment-508861683), however, this symbolic solution is not valid for all values...it is only valid if none of the coefficients in front of the symbols for which you are solving are zero.

Comment: Thank you, the matrix calculation is faster than the method like https://scaron.info/blog/solving-symbolic-equations-with-sympy.html